# Windows 10 - Perl vs. dsadd/dsquery

Tags: windows, active-directory, perl, windows-10

I created a perl script for adding users to Active Directory a few months ago. On Windows 7 it runs fine. On Windows 10 perl is not able to run "dsquery" or "dsadd" but I can really not understand this.

When I run "dsquery" from the same command line, it works. Trying with the perl script... It won't!

```
Der Befehl "C:\Windows\System32\dsquery.exe" ist entweder falsch geschrieben oder konnte nicht gefunden werden.
```

(= Command dsquery could not be found...)

Some code snippets from the perl script:

```
$datetime = strftime("%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S", localtime);
&GetOptions     ("-v=s"    => \$fname,
             "-n=s"    => \$sname,
             "-u=s"    => \$uname,
             "-p=s"    => \$pwd,
             "-noshare" =>\$noshare,
             "-test"   =>\$test,
             "-noquota"   =>\$noquota,
             "-sshpw=s"   =>\$sshpw );

unless ($fname) {                
print "Vorname: ";
$fname = <STDIN>;
chomp $fname;}

unless ($sname) {
print "Nachname: ";
$sname = <STDIN>;
chomp $sname;}

unless ($uname) {
$uname =  substr($fname, 0, 1);
$uname = "$uname.$sname";}
$uname = lc($uname);

if (`C:\\Windows\\System32\\dsquery.exe user -samid $uname`){
print "Benutzer $uname existiert bereits!";
exit;}
```

At this point it already stops.
But, when I run:

```
c:\windows\system32\dsquery.exe user -samid ANYUSER
```

it works.

What is happening right here? Can anyone undestand this??

Cheers,
Lukas

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm guessing you've a 32 bit install of Perl on a 64 bit OS. There isn't a 32 bit version of `dsquery.exe` in `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\` on Windows 10 AMD64. From the 'Run' dialog compare the results of the following.

With 32 bit `cmd`:

```
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cmd.exe /K C:\windows\system32\dsquery.exe
```

Then explicitly using 64 bit `cmd`:

```
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /K C:\windows\system32\dsquery.exe
```

Or just

```
DIR C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dsq*.*
DIR C:\Windows\System32\dsq*.*
```

If you really want to run 64 bit `dsquery.exe` from a 32 bit environment try using the [`sysnative`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384187(v=vs.85).aspx) alias.

```
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cmd.exe /K C:\windows\sysnative\dsquery.exe
```

Try this in your script, no guarantees that Perl won't just choke on it.

```
if (`C:\\Windows\\sysnative\\dsquery.exe user -samid $uname`)
```